# Finding kth smallest elements from A union B

Tags: arrays, algorithm

In 2 sorted array A and B each of size n how to find kth smallest element in A union B in just O(log n) time? I know it takes O(n) to find A union B.

Comment: Did we say that we're bored and need a puzzle to while away time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in O(log n) time in the following way :

Main thing to be done : Since the arrays are sorted, you can use binary search to find element of A in B.

Overall solution : http://leetcode.com/2011/01/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-union-of.html

Comment: Yeah that link provided the solution.But repeatition was not allowed they it can be solved in O(k)